# Cannot open application in Quickly

Tags: python, gtk, quickly, pygtk, webkit

I'm creating web browser in Quickly. When I am running my application (quickly run) I have errors about gtk. Without the WebKit code it can run. Sorry about my english.

```
Errors: 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type 'PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's  'GtkCellRenderer' class size
from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
from gtk import _gtk
```

Application code: http://pastebin.com/ZrTzggXd

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing old static bindings and new dynamic bindings.

Old examples: `import gtk`, `import gobject`, `import webkit`

New examples: `from gi.repository import Gtk`, `from gi.repository import GObject`, `from gi.repository import WebKit`

Your code is very simple to port. Change the following lines:

```
# Line 16
from gi.repository import WebKit

# Line 35
self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
```